# Auto get type with type erasure--putting different type of pointer in to one array

Tags: c++, type-erasure, decltype

I am trying to writing a little library of type erasure.

I want to let the value returned with correct type automatically different from **boost::any_cast**.

In my method, I have to let below code work.

```
#include <typeinfo>   

class A;
class B;
class C;
A* aptr;
B* bptr;
C* cptr;

vector<void*> typeArr;
typeArr.push_back(aptr);
typeArr.push_back(bptr);
typeArr.push_back(cptr);

typeid(decltype( *(typeArr[0]) )).name(); //A
typeid(decltype( *(typeArr[1]) )).name(); //B
typeid(decltype( *(typeArr[2]) )).name(); //C
```

Is it possible?

Comment: maybe similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512756/c-how-to-create-a-vector-storing-vectors-of-any-type/39514479#39514479

Comment: But that solution return "any" as the type.
In the code in that solution: auto anything = va.at(0).at(1);
decltype( va.at(0).at(1) ) is "any"
I want to let the type of return value be specific, and can be use to cout/cin.