# unknow size templated map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

My problem is easy and I think the solution is obvious but I couldn't figure it out (even after googling).

I want to create a std::map containing many differents objects (int, char, ...) 
so I thought about telmplate.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <map>

 using namespace std;


 template<typename T>
 std::map <std::string, T> myMap;
...
```

When I compile I have this error

```
error C2133: 'myMap' : unknown size
error C2998: std::map<std::string,T> myMap' : cannot be a template definition
```

So how to resolve that !!

Thank you

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804955/heterogeneous-containers-in-c

Comment: You cannot use a type placeholder in a variable definition. You always have to specify a type.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about, waht you are trying to achive?

Comment: @kiloalphaindia : I want to insert into my Map let's say strings as first and sometimes integers smetimes strings as seconds

Comment: This is probably a dup of :https://stackoverflow.com/q/39512756/7637816

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::any>` or `std::map<std::string, std::variant<..>>` ?

Comment: Warning: This can turn into a book-keeping nightmare. Be honest with yourself on why you need to have this and exhaust more than a few alternatives before going with it.